# Jobs magically disappear from queue (delayed_job mongoid 2 on heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mongoid, delayed-job

lets say i do something like

```
arrs = Article.where(:body => nil)
```

i'll have arrs.count is let's say 900
and i do

```
arrs.each do |ar|
  ar.delay.download_via_diffbot #a method that takes some time, does some http, and writes a non-nil value to ar.body
end
```

now i'll watch the logs, and a wait a few minutes on ~5 dynos do the jobs, and do a count again: arrs.count is now ~800

### so wtf, i thought i just told my workers to do ~900 jobs, what happened to the other 800?

i can confirm that i'm only making ~100 HTTP requests b/c the api reporting shows me this, also simply watching the logs is telling enough that 900 jobs are not happening.

---

### I'm following the Delayed::Job.count and only about 100 are created from that loop, even though there are multiple hundred jobs to start with

Am I creating this many simultaneous jobs incorrectly?
What's the proper way to create so many jobs at once?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid criteria are lazy loaded/evaluated. That is to say if you set `articles = Article.where(body: nil)`, articles is a criteria. It is not the set of documents you get from db. So if you delete some articles with body `nil` or fill in body of some articles, `articles.count` will fire another db query and only report number of articles for which body is nil. Reducing count is to be expected if your delayed workers are successfully doing their job and filling up body content.

PS: Question was not very clear, I just answered to what I comprehended the problem is.

**UPDATE**

You can check the delayed job count to see how many jobs are pending at any time by `Delayed::Job.count`. If you are not deleting the failed jobs, you can check the count of failed jobs by `Delayed::Job.where(:failed_at.ne => nil).count`. To see more details about failed jobs, you can inspect the job, it will have the handler and last error.

Comment: I understand that part, the problem I'm having is even though I'm creating these jobs in the loop, only a fraction of them seem to actually be attempted. I'm using the count as another way to measure completion on top of counting the api calls.

Comment: It seems all fine, initially you had 900 jobs with nil body. You make 100 api calls which fill in body, so you are left with 800 jobs with nil body. Am I missing something here??

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the loop should have queued 900 jobs.

Comment: Ahh... now I got it, you feel that all the queued jobs have already completed. if that is the case, you should check the delayed job count.

Comment: That's it though, 800 of those jobs were never attempted in the first place. If they were, and failed, I would have seen the attempts in the logs, and have seen 800 more api calls.